# BitmapFactory.Options inPreferredConfig makes no difference to image file

Tags: android, android-bitmap

Am I correct in saying that if I take a full resolution picture with the camera, and save the bitmap as a jpg using bitmap.compress(), the inPreferredConfig parameter makes no difference at all to the final image?

I have tried specifying both, and the resulting images are the same 8-bit per channel jpgs (according to Photoshop) whether or not I use **ARGB_8888** or **RGB_565** modes to create the bitmap. They are both roughly the same file size. So the only way to save heap memory when displaying jpgs is to subsample it like the docs state?

So this is the code I am using, you can see I don't subsample it (scale factor is 1)

```
BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mCurrentPhotoPath, bmOptions);
    int photoW = bmOptions.outWidth;
    int photoH = bmOptions.outHeight;

    /* Figure out which way needs to be reduced less */
    int scaleFactor = 1;
    if ((targetW > 0) || (targetH > 0)) {
        scaleFactor = Math.min(photoW/targetW, photoH/targetH); 
    }

    /* Set bitmap options to scale the image decode target */
    bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    bmOptions.inSampleSize = scaleFactor;
    bmOptions.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.RGB_565;
    bmOptions.inPurgeable = true;

    /* Decode the JPEG file into a Bitmap */
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mCurrentPhotoPath, bmOptions);

    String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
    OutputStream fOut = null;
    File file = new File(path, "TEST_IMAGE.jpg"); // the File to save to
    try {
        fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 85, fOut); // saving the Bitmap to a file compressed as a JPEG with 85% compression rate
        fOut.flush();
        fOut.close(); // do not forget to close the stream

        MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(),file.getAbsolutePath(),file.getName(),file.getName());
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: In-heap sizes are not the same as on-disk sizes. Do not use on-disk sizes to draw conclusions about in-heap sizes. If you want to determine the in-heap size, **measure the in-heap size**.

Comment: @CommonsWare thanks, I am not really concerned about the disk size of the image - question wasn't really clear sorry :) I want to verify that in this set-up, the resultant file is actually better using ARGB_8888. Looking at Android Studio's memory monitor the app's running memory is identical (the image is displayed in an image view). It seems to me that android forces the file format from bitmap.compress() to be the same. Does that make sense or am I crazy?

Comment: "Looking at Android Studio's memory monitor the app's running memory is identical" -- you would be far better served calling `getByteCount()` on the `Bitmap` to determine its byte count. "It seems to me that android forces the file format from bitmap.compress() to be the same" -- I have no idea how `compress()` deals with bit depth of the originating `Bitmap`. However, you say that you are not really concerned about the disk size of the image, and `compress()` is for writing to disk.

Comment: Okay that makes a lot of sense thanks, yes eventually we will need to save the images off and upload them to our server (hence the compress call) I just wanted to verify why the images did not seem substantially different. Looking at getAllocationByteCount reveals the true difference (38mb vs 19mb on my GS4). Want to put that as an answer? I think you could do with the rep ;)

Comment: "I just wanted to verify why the images did not seem substantially different" -- but that amounts to the disk size of the image, which earlier you said you are not concerned about, though apparently you are. As to why `compress()` is giving you the results that you are seeing, I'm not completely sure. My best guess is that the JPEG compression algorithm, particularly at 85 quality, will have a net effect akin to reducing the bit depth, as it derives the color palette to use.

Comment: Well mostly image quality too, I was expecting that if I decoded in RGR_565 and called compress(), the disk file size would be smaller and of a poorer quality, but now I understand that decoding in any manner makes no difference to the result of compress(), so thank you for clearing that up :)